# ng-repeat not showing table rows after loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am experiencing some problems with not showing any data with ng-repeat.

Flow is as follows

I call a sharedObjects service before requesting data from the server, in case the needed data is already loaded and available.

The loading part works, and shows up in the console. There is a timeout set for testing purposes, and the page stays on loading view until data is loaded. But the rows are not showing up the first time. After going to another page and back to the page in question, the data shows fine and is loaded from the sharedObjects service.

My code is as follows

```
// dataService aka sharedObjects
angular.module('app').factory('dataService', function(){
    var List = undefined;
    return {
        getList: function () {
            return List;
        },
        setList: function (list) {
            List = list;
        },
    }
});

// controller
angular.module('appWebmenu').controller('appWebmenuController', ['$scope', 'dataService', 'webmenuService', function($scope, dataService, webmenuService){
    $scope.listLoaded = false; // data is not loaded flag
    $scope.listError = false;  // no errors occured yet flag
    // function to load and pass the data to the ng-repeat
    $scope.getItemList = function(){
        // trying for preloaded data
        $scope.itemList = dataService.getList();
        console.log($scope.itemList);
        if($scope.itemList === undefined){
            // data not previously loaded get from server (service)
            $scope.itemList = webmenuService.getWebmenuList($scope.shop_id,$scope.token)
                // after data loads promise returned
                .then(
                // on success
                function(data){
                    // by adding the extra call to the dataService, it works. Brilliant
                    $scope.itemList = dataService.getList(); 
                    $scope.listLoaded = true; // set the data as loaded
                    return data;
                },
                // on failure
                function(data){
                    $scope.listLoaded = false; // data still not loaded
                    $scope.listError = true;   // an error has occured
                    alert(data.errorMessage);
                });

        }
        else{
            $scope.listLoaded = true; // data returned from preloaded dataService
        }
        return $scope.itemList;
    };



// dataRetrieval which connects to the server

angular.module('appWebmenu').factory('webmenuService', ['$q','$http', 'dataService','$timeout', function($q, $http, dataService, $timeout){
    return {
        getWebmenuList: function (shop_id, token) {
            var dfr = $q.defer();      // init promise
            // set retrieval settings
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: "../api/v1/Webmenu/menulist/all",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: {shop_id: '' + shop_id,token: '' + token }
            };
            // execute retrieval request
            $http(req)
                // when loaded
                .then(
                    // on success
                    function(response){
                        dataService.setList(response.data); // setting the data to the dataService for reuse
                        $timeout(function(){
                            dfr.resolve(response.data);
                        },5000);
                    },
                    // on failure
                    function(response){
                        dfr.reject( false );
                    });
                return dfr.promise;
        }
    };

}]);

// directive

angular.module('appWebmenu').directive('appWebmenuList', function() {
    return {
        //require: '^appWebmenu',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'external/appWebmenu/appWebmenuListTemplate.html',
        controller: 'appWebmenuController',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
        }
    }
});

// Template

<!-- to show while loading -->
<div ng-if="!listLoaded">  // corresponds with $scope.listLoaded in the controller
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
</div>
<!--show when an error occures-->
<div ng-if="listError">    // corresponds with $scope.listError in the controller
    {{ 'ERROR_LOADING' | translate }}
</div>

<!-- show when data is loaded and no errors occured-->
<div ng-if="listLoaded && !listError && itemList">  // check if list is loaded, no errors occured and if itemList is not empty or undefined
    <table class="webmenu-table-main">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{'PAGE' | translate}}</th>
                <th>{{'ACTIONS' | translate}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="item in itemList">

                <script>console.log('menu name is {{ item.menu_name }}');</script>
                <td>{{item.menu_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" title="{{ 'DETAILS' | translate }}" ng-click="details(item.menu_id)" ng-if="item.menu_is_editable != '0'"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-pensil-square" title="{{ 'EDIT' | translate }}" ng-click="edit(item.menu_id)" ng-if="item.menu_is_editable != '0'"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="{{ 'DELETE' | translate }}" ng-click="remove(item.menu_id)" ng-if="item.menu_is_editable != '0'"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" title="{{ 'ADDMENU' | translate }}" ng-click="addNewMenuItem(item.menu_id)"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-external-link-square" title="{{ 'OPENEDITOR' | translate }}" ng-click="openInEditor(item.menu_id)" ng-if="item.menu_is_editable != '0'"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing? This works only the times after the first time when the data is preloaded.

Comment: `$scope.itemList = dataService.getWebmenuList();` shall be `$scope.itemList = dataService.getList()` and `dataService.setWebmenuList(response.data);` shall be `dataService.setList(response.data);` ??
Otherwise, you're merely operating on undefined functions

Comment: Yeah saw it, but I changed some function names for simplicity sake. Must have overlooked those

Answer (score 0):

webmenuService.getWebmenuList returns a promise. Not data. You need to set $scope.itemList inside your `then` function call.

```
if($scope.itemList === undefined){
    // data not previously loaded get from server (service)
    var qListPromise = webmenuService.getWebmenuList($scope.shop_id,$scope.token)
            // after data loads promise returned
            .then(
            // on success
            function(data){
                $scope.listLoaded = true; // set the data as loaded
                return data;
            },
            // on failure
            function(data){
                $scope.listLoaded = false; // data still not loaded
                $scope.listError = true;   // an error has occured
                alert(data.errorMessage);
            });

     qListPromise.then(  function(data)  { $scope.itemList = data;
               }).catch( function(error) { throw error; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just repeated the request to the dataService, That is being set before the promise is returned. Now it works.